# reading a value from a dictionary that doesn't associate with a key

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have this dictionary

```
StudentDictionary = {"156" :{"name":"steve", "lastvisit":"10-02-2012", "age":12}}
```

if I have this dictionary `S = {"name":"steve", "lastvisit":"10-02-2012", "age":12}` I know how to display the age using : `pprint.pprint(S["age"])`

But I don't know how to display the value `ID = 156` or either the `age = 12` from the complex `StudentDictionary`, knowing that `I don't have a key associated with that value.`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to loop through the `StudentDictionary` and match on values. This is not a good solution and will in real life be very slow, and the solution to that is to put this information into a database. But if this is homework or something, it's doable.

You loop through it with

```
for key in StudentDictionary:
```

or

```
for key, value in StudentDictionary.items():
```

Comment: I totally agree with you Lennart and I'm planing to loop through the dictionary and insert the data into a database for further analysis, the only thing is that I don't know how to loop through this kind of dictionary, any hint will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @mongotop You loop through it the same way as any dictionary. `for key in StudentDictionary:` or `for key, value in StudentDictionary.items():`.

Comment: it works!! I can display the ID using `for key in StudentDictionary: print key`. but how can I display the name? pleas  edit your answer so I can accept it. thank you very much!!!

Comment: mongotop: `StudentDictionary[key]` will give you the dictionary containing the name. Or you can use .items() which will give you both the key and the value, as indicated in my previous comment.

Comment: I got this error : 
>>> StudentDictionary["name"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: WhenI do this, I get results.

>>> for key, value in StudentDictionary.items():
...     key
...
'156'

Comment: @mongotop: I didn't write StudentDictionary["name"]. ;-) Try again. I'm not going to spell it out for you, giving you a finished solution is not going to teach you anything useful. :-)

Comment: I got it!!!!!! Thank you very much, this is my learning for today!!! BIG Thanks !!!  
Solution was 
>>> for key, value in StudentDictionary.items():
...     StudentDictionary[key]
...
{'lastvisit': '10-02-2012', 'age': 12, 'name': 'steve'}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27526/discussion-between-mongotop-and-lennart-regebro)

Answer (score 2):

> "because my dictionary has a lot of students"

I think you better to have a database of students, rather than dictionary here.

Answer (score 1):

Like Lennart suggested, for the ID you have to iterate over the items. If using python >= 2.7, you can use dict-comprehension, e.g.:

```
steves = { k: v for k, v in StudentDictionary.iteritems() if v['name'] == 'steve' }
pprint.pprint(steves)
{'156': {'age': 12, 'lastvisit': '10-02-2012', 'name': 'steve'}}
IDs = steves.keys()
```

Comment: Hi shx2, Thank you very much for helping me out, I don't know the name exactly, but I want to display what's on the name key, because my dictionary has a lot of students, so I want to display there id and names.